# T-SQL developer insert & merge stored procedure able to modify to NULL

Tags: sql, t-sql, vba, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a better SQL Server 2008 R2 technique to code the following combined `INSERT` & `UPDATE` procedure that allows NULL `INSERT`?

I am very interested in seeing how other developers write `INSERT` & `UPDATE` procedures that can handle NULL inserts (imagine a user wanting to undo an entry). I appreciate there will be more sophisticated and elegant solutions using `MERGE` or some transaction rollback technique which I am interested in seeing, however, I do ask that you build up your example from first principles as this may result in the post having a wider appeal no matter what the readers T-SQL level.

The basis of this simplistic example is an `Orders` table tracking stock purchases. The procedure should only allow `UPDATES` when the `OrderStatus` is the same or increasing..

```
OrderStatus  Explanation
-------------------------
     0       Creation
     1       Checking
     2       Placement
     3       Execution
     ...
     8       Settlement
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
    OrderID INT IDENTITY,
    Ticker VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Size DECIMAL(31,15) NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(31,15) NULL,
    OrderStatus TINYINT NOT NULL)
```

Further, let's imagine we have the following data so that we can test modifying the data:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [Ticker], [Size], [Price], [OrderStatus]) 
VALUES  (1, N'MSFT', CAST(1 AS Decimal(31, 15)), NULL, 0)
        ,(2, N'GOOG', CAST(2 AS Decimal(31, 15)), CAST(523 AS Decimal(31, 15)), 5)
        ,(3, N'AAPL', CAST(1 AS Decimal(31, 15)), NULL, 0)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Orders] OFF
```

You should have the following data:

```
OrderID Ticker  Size    Price   OrderStatus
-----------------------------------------------
1       MSFT    1.000   NULL    0
2       GOOG    2.000   523.000 5
3       AAPL    1.000   NULL    0
```

Now for the interesting part. This is my best effort to design a combined `INSERT` & `UPDATE` procedure that can deal with NULL inserts (i.e. allow the user to undo an entry). Notice that I need an input parameter to differentiate whether the input value of NULL is intentional and needs to be written into the table vs. the NULL that appears as a missing input parameter. Hopefully it's very clear why I am asking this question as I find my technique very verbose.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Upsert_Orders] @isNullInsert BIT = 0
    ,@OrderID INT = NULL
    ,@Ticker VARCHAR(20) = NULL
    ,@Size VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    ,@Price VARCHAR(100) = NULL
    ,@OrderStatus TINYINT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@OrderID IS NOT NULL)
        -- First check if @OrderID exists
        IF (
                SELECT OrderID
                FROM dbo.Orders
                WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
                ) IS NULL
        BEGIN
            -- @OrderID does not exist therefore replace with NULL
            SET @OrderID = NULL
            PRINT 'spUO. Replaced OrderID ' + CAST(@OrderID AS VARCHAR) + ' input parameter with NULL.'
        END

    IF @OrderID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        -- @OrderID IS NULL so INSERT a new record
        PRINT 'spUO Inserting a new record into the Orders'

        INSERT INTO Orders (
            -- OrderID not needed as IDENTITY new record.
            Ticker
            ,Size
            ,Price
            ,OrderStatus
            )
        VALUES (
            -- @OrderID not needed as IDENTITY new record
            @Ticker
            ,@Size
            ,@Price
            ,@OrderStatus
            )
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- @OrderID IS NOT NULL therefore UPDATE the record @OrderID
        PRINT 'spUO Modifying existing record with OrderID ' + CAST(@OrderID AS VARCHAR)

        -- Declare CurrentVariables for @OrderID
        DECLARE -- @CurrentOrderID INT not needed as @OrderID Found
            @CurrentTicker VARCHAR(20)
            ,@CurrentSize DECIMAL(31, 15)
            ,@CurrentPrice DECIMAL(31, 15)
            ,@CurrentOrderStatus TINYINT

        -- Populate Current Variables from Table Orders
        SELECT -- @CurrentOrderID = OrderID not needed as @OrderID Found
            @CurrentTicker = Ticker
            ,@CurrentSize = Size
            ,@CurrentPrice = Price
            ,@CurrentOrderStatus = OrderStatus
        FROM Orders
        WHERE OrderID = @OrderID

        IF ISNULL(@OrderStatus, @CurrentOrderStatus) >= @CurrentOrderStatus
        BEGIN
            -- Update @OrderID if not moving backwards
            IF @isNullInsert = 0
            BEGIN
                -- We are not updating the record with NULL
                PRINT 'spUO NULL Parameter Input Values get replaced with the existing entries'

                UPDATE Orders
                SET -- OrderID = ISNULL(@OrderID, @CurrentOrderID)  not needed as @OrderID Found
                    Ticker = ISNULL(@Ticker, @CurrentTicker)
                    ,Size = ISNULL(@Size, @CurrentSize)
                    ,Price = ISNULL(@Price, @CurrentPrice)
                    ,OrderStatus = ISNULL(@OrderStatus, @CurrentOrderStatus)
                WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                -- We are potentially overwritting the record with NULL
                PRINT 'spUO Old entries may be overwritten with NULL'

                UPDATE Orders
                SET -- OrderID = ISNULL(@OrderID, @CurrentOrderID)  not needed as @OrderID Found
                    Ticker = @Ticker
                    ,Size = @Size
                    ,Price = @Price
                    ,OrderStatus = @OrderStatus
                WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
            END
        END
        ELSE
            -- User is trying to re-write hostory. Do Nothing
            PRINT 'spUO You do not have permissions to roll back the OrderStatus.' 
    END
END
```

Now that we have an UPSERT procedure, let me illustrate its usage:

Step 1: insert a new row to show the intention to buy some Ford shares:

```
EXEC dbo.Upsert_Orders  @Ticker = 'F',
                        @Size = 1,
                        @Price = 10,
                        @OrderStatus = 2
```

Step 2: let's show that the `OrderStatus` can't be wound back

```
EXEC dbo.Upsert_Orders  @OrderID = 4,
                        @Ticker = 'F',
                        @Size = 1,
                        @Price = 10,
                        @OrderStatus = 1
```

This produces the desired output:

```
spUO Modifying existing record with OrderID 4 
spUO You do not have permissions to roll back the OrderStatus.
```

The data now looks like:

```
OrderID Ticker  Size    Price   OrderStatus
-----------------------------------------------
1       MSFT    1.000   NULL    0
2       GOOG    2.000   523.000 5
3       AAPL    1.000   NULL    0
4       F       1.000   10.000  2
```

Step 3: finally, let's assume the user wants to delete the shares of the first order, then the unfortunate method under my procedure requires the other default parameters be passed and the `@isNULLInsert BIT` needs to be set to 1.

```
EXEC dbo.Upsert_Orders  @isNullInsert = 1,
                        @OrderID = 1,
                        @Ticker = 'MSFT',
                        @Size = NULL,
                        @Price = NULL,
                        @OrderStatus = 0
```

Hopefully this complete example illustrates the concept in adding a new record, updating an existing record and deleting a field of a record. Apologies for the length of this post, but this is the most concise code I was able to produce!

Final data:

```
OrderID Ticker  Size    Price   OrderStatus
------------------------------------------------
1       MSFT    NULL    NULL    0
2       GOOG    2.000   523.000 5
3       AAPL    1.000   NULL    0
4       F       1.000   10.000  2
```

Thanks All,

Bertie.

p.s. This will be called from Excel VBA.

Comment: Will more than one user be calling this at a time?

Comment: Stupid question: why don't you just **delete** the row that you want to "undo"? Why all this complicated inserting a `NULL` into an existing row?? Seems overly complicated and unnecessary....

Comment: The life cycle of an order is such that there are many steps (i.e. OrderStatus) to an order, usually spanning many days. In large firms, many people can be involved in executing an order through to settlement (so locking may be an issue). In the few books I have read, people advocate writing stored procedures to perform INSERT and UPDATE operations. Furthermore, Finance being a regulated industry means I have coded the business/complaiance logic into the procedure (i.e. can't change historical trades). Also, I dont like using DEL & INS excessively when really needing to perforn UPDATE. Thanks

Comment: FYI you can set up your example (table, sample data) here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an answer using merge.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[Upsert_Orders2] 
    @IsNullInsert Bit = 0,
    @OrderID Int = Null,
    @Ticker Varchar(20) = Null,
    @Size Decimal(31,15) = Null,
    @Price Decimal(31,15) = Null,
    @OrderStatus Tinyint = Null
As

Declare @OrderStatusChange Table(Oldstatus int, NewStatus int)

Begin Transaction

Merge
  dbo.Orders As target
Using
  (Select @OrderID As OrderID) As source
On 
  (target.OrderID = source.OrderID)
When Matched Then
  Update Set
    Ticker = Case When @IsNullInsert = 0 Then IsNull(@Ticker, target.Ticker) Else @Ticker End,
    Size = Case When @IsNullInsert = 0 Then IsNull(@Size, target.Size) Else @Size End,
    Price = Case When @IsNullInsert = 0 Then IsNull(@Price, target.Price) Else @Price End,
    OrderStatus = Case When @IsNullInsert = 0 Then IsNull(@OrderStatus, target.OrderStatus) Else @OrderStatus End
When Not Matched Then
  Insert 
    (Ticker, Size, Price, OrderStatus)
  Values
    (@Ticker, @Size, @Price, @OrderStatus)
Output
  deleted.OrderStatus, inserted.OrderStatus into @OrderStatusChange;

If Exists (Select 'x' From @OrderStatusChange Where NewStatus < OldStatus)
  -- Evil History Changer!
  Rollback Transaction
Else
  Commit Transaction
```

Comment: Thanks Laurence, I was able to adapt this excellent answer for my needs. Very elegant solution (compared to my very verbose procedure). Just out of interest, do you use this Merge method as a standard method for inserting into your databases?

Comment: @Bertie I find more use for it in master - detail records, where the user can add/remove/edit the detail records in a batch. I'd probably just have two different procedures for this. You know which you need to call based on whether you have an OrderID or not. I'd consider trying to update an order where the OrderID no longer exists as worth mentioning to the user.